# video file upload to a webserver in iphone

Tags: objective-c, web-services, http, iphone

How to upload video file from my iphone app to a web server? The web server is of php and is configured to handle the upload. I have found for image upload but same is not working with the video file. I have to pass few parameter using POST method and the video file with it. Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Thanks,
Anshu

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're looking for a way to do the `POST` request.

If it is, look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It's the best lib out there to simplify HTTP client stuff (particularly the `ASIFormDataRequest` class).

If you don't know how to select the video, you can do it with `UIImagePickerController`. Documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) and there are good samples on how to work it.